# Null point error in Array when trying to give Buttons in array a color

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, nullpointerexception, scenebuilder

I have an array full of a few buttons and I am trying to go through the array and give each button a color, however I keep getting a null point exception error.

```
   public static Button[] arrayButtons = new Button[33];                
   @FXML public Button btn1 = new Button();
   @FXML public Button btn2 = new Button();
   @FXML public Button btn3 = new Button();

  @FXML
  public void initializeButtonArray() {        
    arrayButtons[1] = btn1;
    arrayButtons[2] = btn2;
    arrayButtons[3] = btn3;
    arrayButtons[4] = btn4;       
  }

   @FXML
   private void test() {

      initializeButtonArray();
      for(Button btn : arrayButtons) {
          btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FF0000");  //error occurs here
      }
  }
```

The error occurs when I try to give all the buttons a color inside my for each loop.

Comment: You're initializing your `Button` array to hold 33 objects, but only assigning 4 of them.  So the other 29 remain `null`.  Also worth noting is that Java is a zero-indexed language, so the first element in your array is `arrayButtons[0]`, _not_ `arrayButtons[1]`.  And finally, you're doing `arrayButtons[4] = btn4`, but you never created `btn4` in the code you've provided, so this code will never compile as-is.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it works now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays Start at 0 so you never set `arrayButtons[0]` to anything leaving it as `null` aka waiting to throw a NullPointer when called.  You also never initialize `btn4` which will throw a null pointer when called and lastly why are you creating a 33 button array when you only initialize 3 the others will throw do you want to guess its a NPE

try this

```
public static Button[] arrayButtons = new Button[4];

public void initializeButtonArray() {  
    arrayButtons[0] = btn1;      
    arrayButtons[1] = btn2;
    arrayButtons[2] = btn3;
    arrayButtons[3] = btn4;      
}
```

Add this

```
@FXML public Button btn4;
```

On your first iteration through the arrayButtons loop it throws a null pointer because its looking for `arrayButtons[0]` but its set as `null` which breaks your whole loop

Also if your referencing a FXML you do not put  `= new Button();`

Comment: omg thank you so much, I'm such a noob at coding ;(, literally spent all day trying to fix this.

Comment: I'd recommend doing `arrayButtons = new Button[] { btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4 };` in `initializeButtonArray` since this way you do not need to change 2 parts of the code when changing the number of elements of the array which decreases possible sources of errors. Also it's shorter...

Answer (score 1):

You initialized only few elements in array. Other are referencing to null.

Change this line of code

```
public static Button[] arrayButtons = new Button[33];
```

to

```
public static Button[] arrayButtons = new Button[4];
```

Note that arrays starts at index 0!